# Stop Cloudant queries returning _design document

Tags: node.js, cloudant, nosql

I am querying a Cloudant database with the NodeJS module, both with specific field searches and also with the function db.list(). However, I am (presumably correctly) also being returned all design documents.

Is there a way to prevent design documents being returned ie when using list, without running a specific query to check the _id, or testing each item of the response from the database?

I cannot find a way to do it in the documentation, only the mention that _design documents are queried and updated like any other document, presumably why there are included in the list.

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind sharing the map function your using to power the list?

Comment: I'm using the Cloudant NodeJS module, which underlying uses nano. The function is inbuilt and can be found here 
https://github.com/dscape/nano#dblistparams-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db.list()` function is accessing Cloudant's _all_docs endpoint e.g.

`https://reader.cloudant.com/animaldb/_all_docs`

This returns all of a databases documents (including design documents) in key order.

As all design documents' ids start with a "_" character we can access only the "real" documents by saying

`https://reader.cloudant.com/animaldb/_all_docs?startkey=%22a%22`

i.e. find my all documents beginning with ones whose keys begin with "a".

In Node.js this looks like:

`db.list({startkey:'a', include_docs:true}, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
})`

Alternatively, you can [create and index](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html) that will allow you to query and return subsets of your database. Design documents are not considered for indexing purposes so would not appear in the result set.

Comment: Thank you, the start key is ideal.